# Node Installation on ubuntu 16.04 (i686)

Tags: apt, software-installation, nodejs

When installing nodejs I get this error

```
Get:1 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x xenial/main i386 nodejs i386 6.9.1-1nodesource1~xenial1 [9,771 kB]
Err:1 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x xenial/main i386 nodejs i386 6.9.1-1nodesource1~xenial1

GnuTLS recv error (-54): Error in the pull function.

E: Failed to fetch deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x/pool/main/n/nodejs/nodejs_6.9.1-1nodesource1~xenial1_i386.deb GnuTLS recv error (-54): Error in the pull function.

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```