# Installing nodejs in linux fails

Tags: nodejs, npm

Am trying to install node js in after uninstalling it but am getting an error

So am doing

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Am getting the error

```
Err:1 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_7.x xenial/main amd64 
nodejs amd64 7.10.1-2nodesource1~xenial1
GnuTLS recv error (-54): Error in the pull function.
E: Failed to fetch https://deb.nodesource.com/node_7.x/pool/main/n/
                        nodejs/nodejs_7.10.1-2nodesource1~xenial1_amd64.deb
                         GnuTLS recv error (-54): Error in the pull function.
```

What could be wrong, when i check

```
node -v
```

Am getting an `The program 'node' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:sudo apt install nodejs-legacy`

so by tryping

```
sudo apt install nodejs-legacy
```

am now getting

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  nodejs-legacy : Depends: nodejs (>= 0.6.19~dfsg1-3~) 
    but it is not going to be installed
```

I have also tried `sudo apt autoremove` to remove any broken dependencies but this doesnt help

where am i going wrong?

Comment: Same GnuTLS error when trying to install node got reported in https://askubuntu.com/q/843056/367990 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/40072609/4464570 but both have no answers. It might be a network issue or a problem with e.g. `curl` or `wget` which might be used to download. Can you try manually downloading the package with `curl https://deb.nodesource.com/node_7.x/pool/main/n/nodejs/nodejs_7.10.1-2nodesource1~xenial1_amd64.deb -o node7.deb` and then installing it using `sudo apt install ./node7.deb`?

Comment: @ByteCommanderam now getting an error  Unsupported file ./node7.deb given on commandline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been able to resolve this issue by using node version manager

Step1

```
Run either:
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.5/install.sh | bash
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.5/install.sh | bash
```

Use either wget or curl

step2

close current terminal and open another

```
nvm ls //should show if you have nodejs previous versions if none itll indicate
```

Step3:
Install latest version of nodejs by today its version 8

```
nvm install v8.6.0
```

check the latest version and replace the numbers

Now nodejs should be installed

```
node -v
npm -v
```

The above steps are also found [Here on this gist](https://gist.github.com/d2s/372b5943bce17b964a79)

Comment: After installing node, don't forget to give it correct permission, see [this guide](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions)

Comment: This should be accepted.